# Facebook data Africa

Tags: data-request, africa

say I want all users along with their friend lists across all of Africa. The user data needs to be georeferenced. Is this possible to obtain?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api

Answer (score 1):

that would be a very lengthy procedure, what you are looking to do is data-scrape using facebook's api. This could be built in python. Take a look on google for a few tutorials. There are some data scrapers that are off the shelf that will help you.